# Detect browser's default search engine in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a piece of code for a Chrome+Firefox extension that redirects users to a search results page for a given string. Currently we redirect to the google search results, and instead of building our own option for search engines, I was wondering if there is a way to use whatever search engine the browser is set to use.

I was wondering if there is a way for a Javascript to detect what search engine the browser is set to? Or to pass on a URI to the browser (Or call a browser API), that the browser then translates to the proper URL for the search results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Firefox, you should take a look at [nsIBrowserSearchService](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/public/nsIBrowserSearchService.idl).

Answer (score 0):

This capability isn't exposed in the Chrome extensions API.  You can file new feature requests like this at crbug.com/new.