# HTML Search link which uses the Default Search Engine

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I want to create a search link on my page.

I can easily create one which uses Google:

`A <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=password+manager" target="_blank">password manager</a> makes it easy to ...`

Is it possible to create a link which uses the browser's default search engine?

Comment: There are a couple of existing discussions about "detecting" the default search engine already, but most of that appears outdated - https://stackoverflow.com/q/2034377/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/27545766/1427878

Comment: @CBroe — Those questions are about browser extensions while this question is about a webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Browsers do not expose either:

- The identity of the user's choice of default search engine
- The ability to pass search terms to that search engine

… through any API accessible to websites the user is visiting.

Answer (score -2):

You can add a Google-powered search engine to your site that shows ads with search results. To add a search engine, you first generate the search box code in your AdSense account and then copy and paste that code into the HTML of your pages.
See https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/160530

Comment: They aren't asking how to restrict the site being searched to their own, and they are asking how to use the search engine of the user's choice, not Google!